# How do I delete an environment I created in Teams Toolkit?

Tags: teams-toolkit

I created an environment in the latest version of the Teams Toolkit but now I would like to remove/delete it.

I tried to right click the name and looked for other options but found nothing. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!